# How to select maximum DATE where row COUNT exceeds a limit in SQL

Tags: sql, filter, count, max

I want to write a query, where I take out data where INPUT_DATE is the maximum, given that I have at least 2 rows on that INPUT_DATE.
So if I would have the following counts on historical days:

| INPUT_DATE | VALUE_A | VALUE_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-25 | 55 | 44 |
| 2022-10-24 | 33 | 22 |
| 2022-10-24 | 51 | 31 |
| 2022-10-23 | 11 | 12 |
| 2022-10-22 | 13 | 14 |
| 2022-10-22 | 15 | 16 |

It should give me the data from 2022-10-24. The max INPUT_DATE where I have more than 1 row.

I have the following, but it is not working as it is either giving a table with >1 row, or no table at all, depending on whether the max INPUT_DATE include more than 1 row or not.

```
select * from (
select VALUE_A, VALUE_B, count(*) over (partition by INPUT_DATE) as cnt
from [db]
where VALUE_C = 'something'
and INPUT_DATE = (select max(INPUT_DATE) from 
    [db] where 
    VALUE_C = 'something' and 
    INPUT_DATE <= '2022-10-25')
    ) t
where t.cnt > 1
```

Desired result:

| INPUT_DATE | VALUE_A | VALUE_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-24 | 33 | 22 |
| 2022-10-24 | 51 | 31 |

Comment: Edited the question as asked for by Jonas Metzler.

Comment: For this you want to use `row_number()` instead of count and filter where it's greater than 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be shorter options and other ways (like row number or partition etc.). But you can get the desired outcome just using `GROUP BY`, `COUNT` and `MAX`. This has the advantage the query will do on every DB type while many functions like row number etc. differ depending on the DB type.

```
SELECT input_date, value_a, value_b 
FROM yourtable
WHERE input_date =
(SELECT MAX(sub.input_date) FROM
(SELECT input_date 
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY input_date
HAVING COUNT(input_date) > 1) sub);
```

You can verify this will produce the correct result here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wbk0Q5nv)